# Can't install cairo-devel and pango-devel on Centos 8.1 (for Tesseract)

Tags: yum, centos-8, dnf, tesseract-ocr

In order to compile the [Tesseract Training programs](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html) from source code, the development packages for `pango` and `cairo` must be installed. However, I'm having trouble installing them on Centos 8.1.

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Centos release 8.1.1911 (Core)

# dnf makecache
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                            58 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                                 20 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - Extras                                                                                              1.7 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - PowerTools                                                                                          129 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00
CERT Forensics Tools Repository                                                                                1.1 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:02
CERT Forensics Tools Repository - Splunk                                                                       1.1 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:02
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                                          11 kB/s | 7.9 kB     00:00
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                 7.5 kB/s | 5.7 kB     00:00
Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                50 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:00
Metadata cache created.
```

Then:

```
# dnf install cairo-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:28 ago on Sun 13 Aug 2023 05:24:52 PM +08.
Error:
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides pkgconfig(gobject-2.0) needed by cairo-devel-1.15.12-3.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides pkgconfig(glib-2.0) >= 2.14 needed by cairo-devel-1.15.12-3.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

And...

```
# dnf install pango-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:35 ago on Sun 13 Aug 2023 05:24:52 PM +08.
Error:
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides pkgconfig(glib-2.0) needed by pango-devel-1.42.4-8.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides pkgconfig(gobject-2.0) needed by pango-devel-1.42.4-8.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides glib2-devel(x86-64) >= 2.56.1 needed by pango-devel-1.42.4-8.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Using `--nobest` gives an even longer list of "nothing provides..." errors. I've tried to first install the two `pkgconfig` packages, but can't find anything that matches.

How can I install pango-devel and cairo-devel?

(Sadly, the OS is fixed at Centos 8.1.1911 and cannot be upgraded)

Answer (score 1):

Both pango-devel and cairo-devel depends on glib2-devel, which in turn depends on glib2.

The version of glib2-devel and glib2 must match but the Centos 8.1.1911 "vault" repo does not have a package with the correct version.

So I found a glib2-devel with a matching version to the installed glib2 package:

```
dnf install https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/x86_64/getPackage/glib2-devel-2.56.4-7.el8.x86_64.rpm
dnf install cairo-devel
dnf install https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/x86_64/getPackage/glib2-devel-2.56.4-7.el8.x86_64.rpm
```